# how to make FlexMDI resize it's child when the window is resized?

Tags: apache-flex

i use the addChild(myChild) on a window. but when this window resizes i want to make the myChild width and height to fit the window. how do I do this?

thanks ;)

Comment: Conceptually, listen to the resize method, and in the resize method invalidateDisplayList.  Then in updateDisplayList you can modify the size and position of your child.  I'm not sure if FlexMDI has special hooks to make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChildName.width = 12;ChildName.height = 12;